# Append DOM element not working with jQuery selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

Try to move selected item from one List to Another but append dom element not working:

```js
//Assign action modules
    $('#Modal_Task #assigned_module').click(function () {
        var list = $("#Modal_Task .unassigned li.ui-selected");
        $('#Modal_Task .assigned').append(list);
        list.remove();
    });


//UnAssign action modules
    $('#Modal_Task #unassigned_module').click(function () {
        var list = $("#Modal_Task .assigned li.ui-selected");
        $('#Modal_Task .unassigned').append(list);
        list.remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade in" id="Modal_Task" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Link Tasks</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row" id="actionee_modal">
                        <div id="info_message_task" class="alert hidden-element dv-message"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 side-box">
                            <label>Unassigned:</label>
                            <div class="selectable-wraper">
                                <ul class="unassigned selectable ui-selectable"><li data-id="3" class="ui-selectee"><strong class="ui-selectee">Title 3</strong></li><li data-id="2" class="ui-selectee"><strong class="ui-selectee">Title 2</strong></li></ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 center-box">
                            <label>Action</label>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="assigned_module"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="unassigned_module"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 side-box">
                            <label>Assigned:</label>
                            <div class="selectable-wraper">
                                <ul class="assigned selectable ui-selectable"></ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_task">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have typos `ui-selectee -> ui-selected`
2. Ur adding the element then instanly removing it. Add a [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

```js
$('#Modal_Task #assigned_module').click(function () {
    var list = $("#Modal_Task .unassigned li.ui-selected");
      $('#Modal_Task .assigned').append(list.clone());
    list.remove();
});


$('#Modal_Task #unassigned_module').click(function () {
    var list = $("#Modal_Task .assigned li.ui-selected");
    $('#Modal_Task .unassigned').append(list.clone());
    list.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade in" id="Modal_Task" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Link Tasks</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row" id="actionee_modal">
            <div id="info_message_task" class="alert hidden-element dv-message"></div>
              <div class="col-md-4 side-box">
                <label>Unassigned:</label>
                <div class="selectable-wraper">
                  <ul class="unassigned selectable ui-selectable">
                    <li data-id="3" class="ui-selected">
                      <strong class="ui-selected">Title 3</strong>
                    </li>
                    <li data-id="2" class="ui-selected">
                      <strong class="ui-selected">Title 2</strong>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 center-box">
                <label>Action</label>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="assigned_module"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right">1</i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="unassigned_module"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left">2</i></button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 side-box">
                <label>Assigned:</label>
                <div class="selectable-wraper">
                  <ul class="assigned selectable ui-selectable"></ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_task">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade in" id="Modal_Task" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Link Tasks</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row" id="actionee_modal">
                        <div id="info_message_task" class="alert hidden-element dv-message"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 side-box">
                            <label>Unassigned:</label>
                            <div class="selectable-wraper">
                                <ul class="unassigned selectable ui-selectable">
                                    <li data-id="3" class="ui-selected">
                                        <strong class="ui-selected">Title 3</strong>
                                    </li>
                                    <li data-id="2" class="ui-selected">
                                        <strong class="ui-selected">Title 2</strong>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 center-box">
                            <label>Action</label>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="assigned_module"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>right</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="unassigned_module"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>left</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 side-box">
                            <label>Assigned:</label>
                            <div class="selectable-wraper">
                                <ul class="assigned selectable ui-selectable"></ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_task">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <script>
   //Assign action modules
   $('#Modal_Task #assigned_module').click(function () {
        var list = $("#Modal_Task .unassigned li.ui-selected");
        $('#Modal_Task .assigned').append(list);
        list.remove();
    });


//UnAssign action modules
    $('#Modal_Task #unassigned_module').click(function () {
        var list = $("#Modal_Task .assigned li.ui-selected");
        $('#Modal_Task .unassigned').append(list);
        list.remove();
    });
</script>
```